# What does "raw" function in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

"Where it's raw and it's the truth."

I came across this sentence was being said in a conversation. I couldn't figure out what "raw" is functioning in this sentence. Is this a kind of phrase or something like that?

Comment: If you are asking for the grammatical function, it's a predicative complement.

Comment: @user178049  I'm not sure about that.  It seems like an ordinary, everyday adjective to me.

Comment: @Andrew it belongs to the category of adjective, but functions as a predicative complement.

Answer (score 1):

"Raw", used about food, means "uncooked", and, when used figuratively, can imply "difficult to digest", "unadorned", "strong", etc.

> 3(of an emotion or quality) strong and undisguised.
>   ‘he exuded an air of raw, vibrant masculinity’
>
> 3.1 Frank and realistic in the depiction of unpleasant situations.
>   ‘a raw, uncompromising portrait’
>
> 3.2US informal (of language) coarse or crude, typically in relation to sexual matters.
>   ‘a campaign against raw lyrics in rock music’

[Raw (Oxford)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/raw)

Comment: thanks for your explanation. In this sentence the word "raw" implies that something offends somebody? It's truth, it offends so it's raw?

Comment: "Raw" does not always mean "offensive".

Comment: of course it's not. I'm just saying why does a person associate these two words; _raw_ and _truth_ with each other in such a way just like in this sentence: "where it's raw and it's the truth."? I like to talk about the context in which this sentence was said. X and Y are in a conversation and Y talked about an infamous incident which was occurred many tears ago and X really offended by that and swore. And Z jumped in conversation by saying "where it's raw and it's the truth."

Comment: We have not seen enough of the conversation to know the exact intention of the speaker who said that something is "raw". In short, the context is missing, because you omitted it.

Comment: Is it something like this: "The polite truth is that Uncle Joe had a bit of trouble with the police. The raw truth is that he was a sex offender who molested little boys and went to prison for ten years."?

Answer (score 0):

Look at definition #3 [here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/raw) from the Oxford Dictionary definition of 'raw'. It means strong and undisguised emotions. The person is bluntly stating exactly what they think, not giving a damn if that offends others.

Michael Harvey got there with the same answer a few minutes before me. I have given him an up vote for winning the race. ;)